# Sending money from a nodejs app using PayPal

Tags: node.js, paypal

I want to create a node app where people can buy a specific service that a seller will provide, and pay for it directly through my site. I want to manage all the transactions to be safe. Is it possible to actually send the sellers the money after I would take a cut for allowing them to sell?

Here is a breakdown:

```
buyer buys sellers service(pays)
             |
money comes to me (handling payments backend)
             |
takes cut
             |
sends money to seller
```

is this possible? Maybe if not with PayPal, maybe stripe of another service that can integrate with NODEJS!?

Answer (score 0):

To accept payments, use PayPal Checkout. Create two routes on your server that return JSON, one for 'Create an order' and one for 'Capture order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

Pair your two routes with the following front-end for the buyer to give their approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

To later send a payment to another PayPal account, the Payouts API might be usable. Details for requesting access are here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Stripe connect with NodeJS: https://stripe.com/en-se/connect/marketplaces.

Here is a tutorial on their web page with the use case you are describing: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide

PayPal also have a platform that you can use: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/platforms/
Although I couldn’t find such a clear example as with Stripe.

Comment: "PayPal also have a platform that you can use" -- no, I would not expect any response from filling out the "PayPal Partner form" linked there.